# Python: format multitline strings with variables

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm writing a Python script at work that contains a part with a large multiline string that also needs to expand variables. I'm used to doing it the following way in Python 2.6 or Python 3:

```
message = """
          Hello, {foo}
          Sincerely, {bar}
          """
print (message.format(foo = "John", bar = "Doe"))
```

However, the server at work is running an old version of Python (2.3.4), which doesn't support string.format. What's a way to do this in old Python versions? Can you do it using the % operator? I tried this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
message = """
          Hello, %(foo)
          Sincerely, %(bar)
          """ % {'foo': 'John', 'bar': "Doe"}
```

I could just do it without using multiline strings, but the messages I need to format are quite large with a lot of variables. Is there an easy way to do that in Python 2.3.4? (Still a Python beginner, so sorry if this is a dumb question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to say

```
message = """
          Hello, %(foo)s
          Sincerely, %(bar)s
          """ % {'foo': 'John', 'bar': "Doe"}
```

Note the `s` at the end, which makes the general format `"%(keyname)s" % {"keyname": "value"}`

Comment: Gotcha, thanks to you and Matt. That's what I was missing, works great now.

Comment: How about concatenating variables?

Comment: @AllDani: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If your question is, "How do I format a string which involves 2 variables interpolated right next to one another then the answers is to do something like ``'Hello %(foo)s%(bar)s' % {'foo': 'x', 'bar': 'y'}``.  (Or you can use the new ``str.format`` approach, which was not an option for the OP since they're on an older version of Python.)

Comment: A multiline set of variables.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
message = """
          Hello, %(foo)s
          Sincerely, %(bar)s
          """ % {'foo': "John", 'bar': "Doe"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary based string formating

```
message = """
          Hello, %(foo)s
          Sincerely, %(bar)s
          """ % { "foo":"john","bar":"doe"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
message = """
          Hello, %(foo)
          Sincerely, %(bar)
          """ % {'foo': 'John", 'bar': "Doe"}
                        ^
```

Replace the single quote with a double quote and it should run just fine.

Comment: Whoops, thanks. I typed it right on the computer, just made my post wrong. Let me edit that out.